# JavaFX: Disable controlling RadioButtons with keyboard

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button, focus

I'm getting started with JavaFX and I have build a little tetris game. Now everything worked fine, but in the end I decided to add a group of radiobuttons to select difficulty - and here I faced a problem:
Suddenly the <kbd>LEFT</kbd>/<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>/<kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys do only switch the radio buttons and do not control the gameplay any more.

To handle the gameplay I have a key pressed event listener added on the scene:

```
public void setKeyEventHandler() {
    game.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(Field::handleKeyEvent);
}

private static void handleKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // ... handle the event to move the figure
}
```

But as I said, this does not execute any more since I added the radio Buttons.
Is there a way to disable changing the radio buttons with keyboard keys and to make them only changeable with mouseclicks?
Do I need to somehow remove the focus from them? But how?

EDIT:
Maybe I should add that I am handling the events for the radio buttons simply using the `setOnAction()` function, for example:

```
classicModeButton.setOnAction((e) -> interestingMode = false); 
interestingModeButton.setOnAction((e) -> interestingMode = true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First approach:**

You could make your `RadioButton`s [not focusable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty).

With this change the default key-listeners for the arrow keys will not change anymore the state of the radios as they will not get focused (even if selected by the mouse):

```
classicModeButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
interestingModeButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

This will only work **if you don't have other focusable `Node`s** on your `Scene`, otherwise they will handle the key-event before it could be handled by the event handler of the screen. If you have other nodes, check the second approach please.

**An example snippet:**

```
// Init the variables
BooleanProperty interestingMode = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
RadioButton classicModeButton = new RadioButton("Classic");
RadioButton interestingModeButton = new RadioButton("Interesting");
ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();

classicModeButton.setToggleGroup(tg);
interestingModeButton.setToggleGroup(tg);
tg.selectToggle(classicModeButton);

// The radios should be not focusable
classicModeButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
interestingModeButton.setFocusTraversable(false);

// On toggle-change, the mode will be changed
interestingMode.bind(tg.selectedToggleProperty().isEqualTo(interestingModeButton));

// Just print the changes
tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        System.out.println((newValue == interestingModeButton) ? "Hmm, interesting" : "Classic .. boring"));

scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> 
        System.out.println((e.getCode().isArrowKey()) ? "Arrow pressed!" : "Other pressed, I don't care!"));
```

---

**Second approach:**

You can handle the key-event by adding an [event filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) rather than an event handler to the `Scene`, and [consume the event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--). This will catch the event already in the capturing phase (rather than the bubbling phase) so the event will not even reach your (focusable) `Node`s:

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    System.out.println((event.getCode().isArrowKey()) ? "Arrow pressed!" : "Other pressed, I don't care!");
    event.consume();
});
```

With this all key-pressed events are captured, but of course it is possible to "let some events" pass.

More about how the events are delivered can be found (for example) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I have never dealt with this situation before, so I am just spitballing an idea here, but perhaps you could implement a handler for `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`.

Within your handler, you could probably get away with saying:

```
if(event.getCode().isNavigationKey()){
    // Some navigation key was pressed
    event.consume(); // prevent further propagation 
    yourGamesControlElement.requestFocus(); // transfer focus
    handleKeyMovementInGame(event.getCode()); // handle the action
}
```

One benefit to this method of detection is that `isNavigationKey()` will handle all of the keycode checks for you, including by checking for both regular arrow keys and number-pad arrow keys.

I would also recommend looking into [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5624145) which discusses using KeyEvents to prevent JavaFX from transferring focus when the Tab key is pressed and the [JavaFX KeyCode documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html) for some additional ideas and implementation details.

Comment: For me, when a Spinner was capturing arrow key presses that I didn't want it to capture, doing `xxxx.requestFocus()` for other the component in scene aside from the errant Spinner helped me.  It probably would work for RadioButtons as well.